# ¿Como pasar los datos de una Jtable a campos que estan en otro JInternalFrame form?

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy haciendo un proyecto donde me piden que al abrir con un botón se me abra otra ventan en la que tendrá un jtable cargado de sql y que al dar clic en ese jtable se guarde el registro en la ventana 2
[image: imagen de mis frame]

lo que pasa es que quiero que cuando le de doble clic en algún registro de la tabla se pase al txt en este caso Status me pidieron que evitara los static y ya intente creando una clase:

```
public class Tabla {
    
     private String ID;
     private String Status;
    public Tabla() {
    }
      public Tabla(String ID, String Status){
          this.ID = ID;
          this.Status = Status;
      }
      
      public String getID(){
          return ID;
      }
      
      public void setID(String ID){
           this.ID = ID;
      }
      
      public String getStatus(){
          return Status;
      }
      
      public void setStatus(String Status){
          this.Status = Status;
      }
      
      @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Status;
    }
}
```

```
  public String getStatus(){
      return Status;
  }
  
  public void setStatus(String Status){
      this.Status = Status;
  }
  
  @Override
public String toString() {
    return Status;
}
```

}

y lo intento guardar de esta manera pero no me sirve:
este es el codigo que esta en la ventana de consulta status para guardarlo en la ventana equipo

```
 Equiponewin eqp = new Equiponewin();
    private void tabla_StatusMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
   
        
        int filaseleccionada = tabla_Status.getSelectedRow();
         
            if (filaseleccionada == -1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha seleccionado ninguna fila");
            }else{
                //aqui intente usar la clase pero sigue sin aparecerme nada 
               // Tabla Status = (Tabla)modelo.getValueAt(filaseleccionada, 1);
                //String  s = Status.getStatus();
                //Tabla IDs = (Tabla)modelo.getValueAt(filaseleccionada, 0);
                //String IDst = IDs.getID();
                //String ID = String.valueOf(tabla_Status.getValueAt(tabla_Status.getSelectedRow(),0));
                txtID.setText(tabla_Status.getValueAt(tabla_Status.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                txtStatus.setText(tabla_Status.getValueAt(tabla_Status.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
             ID = ID;                

             this.eqp.jTextFieldStatus.setText(tabla_Status.getValueAt(tabla_Status.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
             this.eqp.jTextFieldnumStatus.setText(tabla_Status.getValueAt(tabla_Status.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
             //aqui intente hacerlo de otra maner
//             this.eqp.jTextFieldStatus.setText(s);
//             this.eqp.jTextFieldnumStatus.setText(IDst);
//             eqp.setVisible(true);
    }
```

aquí esta como cargo la tabla

```
 public class ConsultaSt extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
    Connection con = null; 
    Statement stmt = null;
    String titulos[] = {"idStatus","statusNom"};
    String fila[] = new String[7];
    DefaultTableModel modelo;
    String ID = "";

    /** Creates new form ConsultaSt */
    public ConsultaSt() {
        initComponents();
        

        
        
           
           
                
        
        try{
            
                String driver = "conexion";
                String user = "usuario";
                String password = "contraseña";
                String url = "conexion a mi base de datos";
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                if(con != null)
                    System.out.println("se establecio una conexion a la base de datos"+"\n"+url);
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from status");
                
                modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null,titulos);
                
                while(rs.next()){
                    fila[0] = rs.getString("idStatus");
                    fila[1] = rs.getString("statusNom");
                    
                    
                    modelo.addRow(fila);
                }
                
                tabla_Status.setModel(modelo);
                TableColumn ci = tabla_Status.getColumn("idStatus");
                ci.setMaxWidth(35);                
                TableColumn cs = tabla_Status.getColumn("statusNom");
                cs.setMaxWidth(165);
                
               

                
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConsultaSt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConsultaSt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConsultaSt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConsultaSt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
    
    }
```

aclaración los 2 son internalfrom.

Listo encontré la forma de pasar los datos pero surgió otro problema que el dato se envía a una nueva ventana como se ve en la imagen siguiente :[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que yo quiero es que el dato se envié a una misma internalframe
aqui esta el codigo que utilize para enviar el dato:

```
private void btnEnviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
// TODO add your handling code here:
int seleccionado= tabla_Status.getSelectedRow();
if(seleccionado == -1){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes seleccionar una fila");       
}else{
    Equiponewin eqps = new Equiponewin();
    if(eqps.isShowing()==false){

        this.getDesktopPane().add(eqps);
        eqps.toFront();
        eqps.setVisible(true);
        
        Equiponewin.txtIDsteq.setText(tabla_Status.getValueAt(seleccionado, 0).toString());
        Equiponewin.txtStatuseq.setText(tabla_Status.getValueAt(seleccionado, 1).toString());
        
    }else{
        Equiponewin.txtIDsteq.setText(tabla_Status.getValueAt(seleccionado, 0).toString());
        Equiponewin.txtStatuseq.setText(tabla_Status.getValueAt(seleccionado, 1).toString());
    }              
}
```

}

Comment: ¿ _JInternalFrame_ ? Por cierto, los snippets son para códigos HTML + CSS + JS. Esto es java. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Por último, _workbench_ no tiene relación con la pregunta. Coloca solo las etiquetas relevantes: [java] y [java-swing], en este caso.

Comment: ok gracias, listo espero que ahora si este bien